# Separate all layers every "X" interval of time in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I dropped +100 images in After Effects, I would like to make a simple slideshow, and for this I have to separate/slice each layer sequentially every 5 seconds (that is the duration I want for each image/transition).

Please see the image below to understand better what I mean:

[image]

So, I wonder if exists a simple technique to do this programatically with all the layers, instead of manually dragging one per one. Maybe a simple hotkey combination to move the start of the layer to the current position in the timeline, or better a built-in feature like "Expressions" or maybe a external script or plugin for AE?.

### UPDATE:

I found a expression example that I think it could be helpful for what I want, however, I can't find the way to adapt it for the simple task that I require. (my After Effects knowledges are very basics)

- [Expression example: Create a trail of images](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-examples.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No scripting or expressions are needed, it's built-in to After Effects:

1. Drop all your frames into a comp…
2. go to the 5 second mark…
3. with all layers selected, hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to trim the end of the layer to the current time…
4. still with all the layers selected either right-click or go to the top menu and choose **Animation>Keyframe Assitant>Sequence Layers**…
5. in the dialog that comes up you can choose to overlap the layers and to add dissolves. Usually for a slideshow you will choose to dissolve the top layer only. Dissolving top and bottom layers mean that the background shows through in the middle of the dissolve.